# How to increase query performance at Sql Server 2000 and compare Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, database-performance, query-performance

I have complex query and big database.I execute my query on the Sql Server 2008 it took time 8-10 minute.But I execute my query on the Sql Server 2000 it took time 1-2 hour.Why?I used index and I used execution plan but I didn't solve this problem.Anybody can help me? or Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly create an auxiliary table for this query. That way the query would run faster, since the work is done before the query in background. Note: This usually works if the query retrieving the data doesnt have to be in sync with the DB.
Also, It depends on how you want to use the data, you might be able to cache or precache the results.